# c# ClientCertificates.Add() certificate not attached to httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest, x509certificate, client-certificates

I'm grabbing a self-signed piv auth X509certificate from a smart card inserted in a USB reader and am attaching it to the HttpWebRequest via the code below:

```
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriInfo);
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(theCert);
Request.Method = "POST";

//get the response back (the mini driver will prompt for a PIN at this point)
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

Here is the thing that is confusing me, this code works on some machines but not on others. It's worked on Win7 on one machine and not on Win7 on another, it works in Win8. I've even tried running it in a Virtual Machine of Win8 which works, which is a guest of a Win7 host machine that doesn't work.

I've read a lot of articles on stack overflow, and tried many different things to get this to work, but nothing seems to.  Since my certificate doesn't contain the private key info, that seems to be why it is not included in the request? Which is similar to this question: [HttpWebRequest doesn't seem to be sending a client SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514628/httpwebrequest-doesnt-seem-to-be-sending-a-client-ssl-certificate)

Since it works on some machines and not others is this something I need to configure differently on the machines where it is not working?

I know the cert is not being attached because of some wireshark investigating.  The certificate I'm using has been set up on the server, so it should trust it (and does in some cases).

Some things I'm doing different than other posts is I'm getting the cert from a piv smart card and simply attaching it to the request. When I call GetResponse, the microsoft minidriver steps in a prompts for a PIN to be entered. But since the certificate is not being attached to the request, I never get the prompt for the PIN and the server returns a 403 Forbidden error.

Any ideas?

(This is my first post here, so please forgive any sins which I've committed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out what the problem was. I noticed that the when the smart card was inserted into the reader, the certificate was not propagated to the personal store.  Then I found that the thing responsible for doing this was the a service called "Certificate Propagation".

I noticed that service was not running and when I tried starting it, it would stop right away giving the message,

> "The Certificate Propagation service on Local Computer has started
>   then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use
>   by other services or programs."

After some digging on why this service would start but not stay running I found it was due to a Group Policy setting stashed in the registry. Changing the following registry setting from 0 to 1 fixed the issue for me:

```
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Certprop\CertPropEnabled = 1
```